# Powdered Goat Milk in Bread?

Tags: substitutions, bread, milk

A lot of my favorite bread recipes call for powdered milk (cow's milk). Particularly in some of the tangier breads, it would seem that goat's milk might be really tasty. Is there anything I should know before buying powdered goat's milk and using it in bread? It's spendy stuff, so an answer of "it's not worth the money" could be useful, particularly from someone who has actually tried it.

Comment: One thing I see from the label is that the powdered goat's milk in my store is full-fat; I've only ever used non-fat dry milk in bread. I doubt that will require any tweaking, but it seems worth putting out there.

Comment: Goats milk is pretty wild, generally it is the second wildest milk behind sheep's milk. You are giving your goods a very specific taste that is not going to be widely liked. It can be used as a substitute for milk but in baked goods their is going to be the issue of fat content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used goat milk in my baking because I don't like the taste of goats milk. I suspect it would be a good idea for you to taste goats milk first to see if you like it if you haven't already. Other than that, there's no reason to not use it.

As far as fat content goes, I only use full-fat dairy in my bread. No adjustments to the recipe are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Goat milk is highly prized in baked goods and for those with digestive issues. I've used it often but because it is richer and costlier freezing it is a good option for leftovers. As the previous poster pointed out it is heavy on the fat content.

Answer (score 1):

I've have now done it, and it's lovely. It gives a very slight tang to the bread, almost like a little nod to sourdough. I definitely like that it's full-fat, it's just richer. I used this: [Powdered Goat's Milk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004K69OMU) which is available in most grocery stores here (at drastically different prices, one store's normal price is three times another store's normal price). Interestingly, I cannot find a local source for full-fat powdered cow's milk, making this item even more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a loaf of bread with the addition of two unpacked scoops of powdered goat's milk and it is fantastic. Without the addition of the powdered goat's milk, the bread was plain, plain, plain. It was like eating a blank piece of paper, and was also dense. Almost like a bagel, but not as chewy. This new loaf, however, is creamy, flavorful, and it's lighter and springier. I'm glad I had the powdered goat's milk on hand. This pandemic is making me learn all sorts of ways to think outside of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If concerned about a difference in fat content, you can buy nonfat powdered goat milk! I am allergic to cow dairy but can handle some goat dairy. I use it in bread but use the nonfat to keep the fat ratios the same.

Comment: Welcome to SA, Shea!  Your comment is interesting, but it doesn't address the asker's question.  If you have experience with powdered goat milk in bread, maybe you could share them to more directly address the question?